# Pattern matching BigInts

Tags: scala

This factorial implementation works for numbers up to a certain size:

```
def factorial(n:Int):Int = n match {
    case 0 => 1
    case x => x * factorial(x - 1)
}
```

I tried to use BigInt to make it work for numbers of any size like this

```
val zero = BigInt(0)
def factorial(n:BigInt):BigInt = n match {
    case zero => 1
    case x => x * factorial(x - 1)
}
```

Every call to *factorial* comes back with 1 regardless of the value of n.  I assumed this is because the first case is always matching, and proved it is so by changing it to

```
case zero => 22
```

and verifying that 22 was returned for every input.

So my **two** questions are

1. Why is the first case always matching?
2. Is there a way to get a BigInt version of this function to work whilst sticking to pattern matching?

Comment: You can also make the val start with a capital letter, like `Zero`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should either rename `zero` as `Zero` or use it like this:

```
case `zero` => 1
```

Comment: could you explain what this syntax is ? I am new to scala

Comment: @jtkSource See **Variable or constant?** in [Programming in Scala/Case Classes and Pattern Matching](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html)

Answer (score 3):

To match against a variable wrap it with " ` "

```
val zero = BigInt(0)
def factorial(n:BigInt):BigInt = n match {
    case `zero` => 1
    case x => x * factorial(x - 1)
}
```